# Page cached tracking using javascript

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, browser-cache

How to check whether the page is cached in browser using javascript in all browser? I want to execute one javascript function only on when back button is pressed in a browser.

Comment: Why does it matter if it is cached? The point of a cache is to provide an opaque interface (that is, you don't know, don't care if it's cached) to retrieve information, while improving performance...

Comment: Hi Jeremy, I am executing two javascript function. One for new page request and another one for when back button is pressed.

Comment: Hmm, I think I'd need a little more information in order to help you solve this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can achieve this using JQuery [History](https://github.com/balupton/history.js) plugin.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
$('body').append('<div class="is_cached"></div>');
});

History.Adapter.bind(window,'statechange',function(){
if($('.is_cached').length >= 1)
{
  alert('this page is cached');
}
});
```